# Record level permissions

Tags: sql, security, permissions

In a database I am designing I have implemented profile based object level security.

Each user can view, edit, insert, update database tables according to the profiles (roles) he is a member of.

Now there is a need to implement "External Users" who can view only the relevant records and edit some of them (but not the bulk of the database).

I am working on an "record ownership" model.

Are there any ideas on how to restrict the users belonging to an "External Users" profile to see and work with some records of each table, but not all.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably create a VIEW which limits the records and then apply the proper rights on the view.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a VIEW, or you could create select stored procedures and only assign rights to those.

The VIEW is the way to go for a simple security model - if it is complex, go with the stored procedure(s).

Answer (score 0):

I have my first draft. It goes like that:

The app is a Project Management/Issue Tracking/Event Management/Collaboration Web app.

I created a Role "External User". By default a user in that role

- can SELECT FROM Persons

  can SELECT FROM Units (organizational units-companies-depts etc)

  can SELECT Projects assigned to him

  can SELECT Tasks assigned to him

  can not SELECT any other Projects & Tasks

The administrator can create a user group "External Partner" and assign to that some Projects and Products (with Issues)

The members of this group can SELECT the assigned Objects.

It is a complicated solution, but the only one that solves my customers problem (they don't want external partners to have access to all their project database).